# Versatile, lightweight and free programming language that runs on desktop and cloud

Tags: web-services, web-applications, cross-platform, desktop-application

I'm a IT student and I (need to) write small desktop and web apps from time to time.
I've used RealBasic a few times but I'm pretty sure theres better languages.

Those are my requirements:

- Run on Windows/OS X and Linux
- Have a webframework available like Node.js for js, vibe for D, etc
- A nice IDE/Text editor with support for the language (code completion) for OS X
- Free
- Run native, or a small portable VM lika Dao or have it packed like Delphi and RealBasic
- Not Ruby (sorry)

I'm open to all sorts of languages, D looked the best with the combination of Vibe.d, but after spending a day trying to set it up properly on OS X I dropped it.

Comment: Have you tried Python? It's installed by default on OS X and almost every Linux distro.

Comment: I haven't tried Python - I was told it was slow, had bad desktop GUI support and hard to distribute.

Comment: [Squeak](http://www.squeak.org/Download/‎)?

Comment: @krtek: Depends what you use it for. If it's computation, Numpy and Scipy are only a bit slower than C for most tasks. Python has PyGTK and PyQt4/PySide, which are excellent bindings for GTK and Qt4. Distributing it isn't difficult either with Py2exe and Py2app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python:

- Pre-installed on OS X and 99% of all Linux distros. Easily installable on Windows.
- Python has Flask, Bottle, Django, web2py, web.py, and quite a few more.
- I use [Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com/). TextWrangler is also fairly good, but I don't remember if it had support for code completion.
- Free.
- You can use [Py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/) and [Py2app](http://pythonhosted.org/py2app/) to make standalone executables.
- Not Ruby.

Python's web frameworks are excellent and PyQt4/[PySide](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Category%3aLanguageBindings%3a%3aPySide) are complete Python bindings for Qt4.

Comment: And theres a HUGE amount of documentation, tutorials, examples, open source projects, etc. Thanks.